# Identifying the server from which a Delphi 7 program is run

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Separate versions of a Delphi 7 program have been deployed on various servers. 
In order to help troubleshoot reported errors, I'm trying to write a function to identify what server the program is running from.

The following code gets me the local computer name.

```
sbAll.Panels.Items[1].Text := 'Server: ' + GetEnvironmentVariable('COMPUTERNAME');
```

Assuming that the absolute path of the program is:

```
\\Swingline\Programs\Folder\Program.exe
```

How do I get it to return `Server: Swingline` regardless of what computer it is run from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use Application.ExeName, split it by the slashes and get the second element...

Comment: Does this work even when the network location has been mapped to a drive letter?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I ended up using based on @Zdravko's suggestion.

```
List := TStringList.Create;
try
  ExtractStrings(['\'], [], PChar(Application.ExeName), List);
  if (List.Text[2] = ':') then  // On local computer, Ex. J:\Programs\Foo.exe
    sbAll.Panels.Items[1].Text := 'Server: ' + ntComputer.ComputerName
  else   // In the case of \\Swingline\Programs\Folder\Program.exe
    sbAll.Panels.Items[1].Text := 'Server: ' + UpperCase(List[0]);
finally
  List.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using a string list...

```
function ExeLocation: String;
var
  S: String;
begin
  S:= ParamStr(0);
  if Copy(S, 2, 2) = ':\' then begin
    Result:= GetEnvironmentVariable('COMPUTERNAME');
  end else
  if Copy(S, 1, 2) = '\\' then begin
    Delete(S, 1, 2);
    Result:= Copy(S, 1, Pos('\', S)-1);
  end;
end;
```

Keep in mind that if you are referencing the file by the machine's IP address, this will only return the IP address. For example `\\192.168.1.123\SomeFolder\SomeFile.exe` would just return `192.168.1.123`. I looked for other ways but I'm not knowledgeable enough in that department to dig deep enough for the true machine name. It might be possible, but I'm just not seeing it possible.